# Solve mod equation in JS

Tags: javascript, equation-solving, modulo

I need to find an `x` value that satisfied:

```
x * a % m == b
x * c % n == d
```

Is there a smarter way to find the solution without iterating all the possibilites ?

```
function solve()
{
    for (x=0;x<n*m-1;x++)
    {
        if((x * a % m == b) && (x * c % n == d))
             return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you have (know) the b and d values and the only missing piece is x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no direct correlation between these two equations (excepted the unkown X), I don't think that you can solve it in a really clever way. However, perhaps should you give a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem. This will not provide an answer to the topic itself, but could lead you to find some alternatives.